# Returning Json objetcs in Chrome using ASp.Net Web Apis

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am fairly new to web API and i'm currently following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api)
I have only got as far as task 3 and i'm quite learning  a lot.

As you can see the tutorial is using Internet Explorer and I am using Chrome .. for some reason Chrome is returning `xml` and IE is returning a `json` object. Should I worry about this or not? i'd love it if Chrome returned a Json object though..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebApi is pretty cool in that it will serialise it's output as JSON or XML based on the accept header sent by the browser.

I expect that Chrome's default is XML, and IE's is JSON.

I can't find a simple configuration change example for Chrome, with most information pointing to having to use a plugin to change the accept header. In Firefox the default is XML but you can adjust it with a config change.